# What is the optimal way to call N blocking api calls in parallel to get most out of CPU while waiting for api calls to complete?

Tags: java, concurrency, microservices

I am working on a micro-service which have following flow of operations :

[image]

A request comes to execute some number of tasks. After some pre-processing I know that I need to execute some number of tasks let's say 10. Now the tasks are independent of each other, so can be executed in parallel. And each task have some processing step and some external API calls.  And after all tasks are completed the combined results need to be returned.

This is one request, so obviously this micro service can get many such requests in parallel too.

Here API calls are most time-consuming operations and other work executes in very less time comparatively. So I want to design this in a way that as many tasks can be executed in parallel because for tasks mostly would be blocked for API calls.

A simple solution I see is using a thread-pool using ExecutorService, but it doesn't seem like a ideal solution because let's say I create a thread pool of 32 threads, and I get 60 tasks. So only 32 would be executing at a time, even though those 32 tasks are blocked for api call and not using much CPU time.

Is this possible to achieve without breaking the task as a single unit ?

Comment: Have a look at `CompletableFuture` and `CompletableFuture.all()`

Comment: CompletableFuture by default uses inbuilt forkjoin thread pool, or we need to use it with a different thread pool, which gives same problem I talked about. We can run only as many tasks as many threads we have in thread-pool.

Comment: You have to create all of your completable futures, in one go, using `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` and then save them in a `List`. Once you've done that you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf()` to wait on all. You're right that maybe only a subset may be executed. But `CompletableFuture.allOf()` will wait until *all* are executed.

Comment: So create a larger thread pool? If the tasks are mostly blocking it hardly matters how large it is.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` uses the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` if nothing else is provided, so yes. You'd have to create an `Executor` with a big enough pool behind it

Comment: The optimal solution would be to break a task into k non-blocking subtasks, which can spawn new subtasks when necessary. But you don't want to break a task. You may be interested in coroutines in Kotlin to simulate an unbreakable task, whose execution is actually interleaved with the execution of other code.

Answer (score 3):

The optimal number of threads depends on the number of cores the server has and the time the I/O workload takes. See http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2013/06/01/optimum-number-of-threads/ to calculate that.

In short it states: `threads = number of cores * (1 + wait time / service time)`

The timings has to come from your observation and measurements.
For the rest, you can use the `CompletableFuture` as mentioned in the comments or you can use the `Executors` class: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(<num of threads>);`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do some benchmarking to figure out what is optimal for your setup. You might want to look into using `ThreadPoolExecutor` which can scale up and down the number of threads according to how many threads are available in the pool. There are a few parameters you can adjust in your benchmarks, namely `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this is to ensure that the thread pool alway contains at least `n` threads in the runnable state (where `n` is usually equal to the number of CPU cores). This implies that you need to manage blocking and whenever a thread starts blocking add a thread to the pool and remove it again once it comes out of blocking.

Java's [`ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html) is part of a solution for a similar problem when working with [parallel streams](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue223.html).

Scala generalises and simplifies this aspect through the [`ExecutionContext`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.html) used when working with [futures](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `TheadPoolExecutor` has some control parameters (core pool size *(<32)*, maximum pool size *(60)*), allowing 60 threads for 32 cores would work well when 28 active threads are blocked.

The constellation you describe would often utilize a *task queue*, but you asked for the most CPU utilizing strategy. Though with microservices other aspects (than cores) play a role too.